# What am I doing wrong in a string to double conversion?

Tags: java, string, swing, double

I just bought a book on Java coding after taking a class a few years ago. I decided to start writing a program to get back in the swing of things. Anyways, my program to calculate the volume of a cylinder is having issues. Could you please critique it and tell me what's going on? If it's any help, I'm using JCreator.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Cylinder_Volume
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        string input;
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the radius of the cylinder?");
        double r;
        r=double.parsedouble(input);
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the height of the cylinder?");
        double h;
        h=double.parsedouble(input);
        double pi=3.1415926535;
        double volume=pi*r*r*h;
        System.out.println("The volume of the cylinder is: "+volume+".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: You might consider looking at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Answer (score 3):

2 errors

1) it's `String` not `string`
2) `double.parsedouble` not correct it should be `Double.parseDouble`
don't forget java is `case sensitive` and method names have `camel case`

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Cylinder_Volume
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String input;//first error you have types string //s should be capital
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the radius of the cylinder?");
        double r;
        r=Double.parseDouble(input);//2nd problem
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the height of the cylinder?");
        double h;
        h=Double.parseDouble(input);
        double pi=3.1415926535;
        double volume=pi*r*r*h;
        System.out.println("The volume of the cylinder is: "+volume+".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use `Double.parseDouble(input)` instead of `double.parsedouble(input)`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that it was the capitalization screwing me over.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Double.parseDouble(0.0);
```

Use `Double` as an object, not a primitive. The call on the object, returns the primitive `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Cylinder_Volume
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String input;
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the radius of the cylinder?");
        Double r;
        r=Double.parseDouble(input);
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the height of the cylinder?");
        Double h;
        h=Double.parseDouble(input);
        Double pi=3.1415926535;
        Double volume=pi*r*r*h;
        System.out.println("The volume of the cylinder is: "+volume+".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look like follwing:
import javax.swing.*;

```
public class CandidateCode
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String input;
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the radius of the cylinder?");
        double r=Double.parseDouble(input);
        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the height of the cylinder?");
        double h=Double.parseDouble(input);;
        double pi=3.1415926535;
        double volume=pi*r*r*h;
        System.out.println("The volume of the cylinder is: "+volume+".");
    }
}
```

There are couple of changes that I've made to it.

1. Its `String` and not `string`.
2. To parse double you should use `Double` class as `double` is primitive type.